# Deleted Linux Partition , Stuck on grub rescue , Cannot load any OS

Tags: linux, ubuntu, boot, windows-10, grub

I installed Fedora on my computer by freeing up 20GB from the E drive in Windows 10 . But i realised that i didn't like the interface much , so i went back to windows disk management and noticed that 20GB of space was still free and so without deleting anything on it , i put all that space back into my E: drive on windows 10 . Now , after i restarted my computer , i got stuck on grub rescue which says `Error : Unknown Filesystem` . After some research on google , i found out that it was due to me deleting that linux partition which also deleted the grub bootloader which handled the booting of Windows and Linux . I found the following solutions to help me :

1)Repair the MBR bootloader which the Windows originally used by going into the command prompt using the Windows 10 bootable usb and putting in the command `BootRec.exe /fixmbr` .

The bootable windows 10 usb ends up getting stuck in the restart loop i.e. on the windows logo loading screen with the white dots moving in a circle .

2)Use a Ubuntu or any other Linux distro live usb and run gpart to format my HDD

I have tried to run/install Fedora , Ubuntu and Mint but they always get stuck in the process . Ubuntu always reports many errors like "Out of memory" "Kill process or sacrifice child" in a list whenever i try to "Try Ubuntu without installing" or "Install Ubuntu"

3)Use the following commands in the grub rescue terminal :

```
set boot=(hd0,msdos7)
set prefix=(hd0,msdos7)/boot/grub
insmod normal
normal
```

This did get me to the grub menu which showed me the OS available on my HDD (Ubuntu and Windows 10) but whenever i clicked on Windows 10 , it got stuck in the restart loop i.e. at the windows logo loading screen and whenever i clicked on Ubuntu , it got stuck on a blank screen .

Please help .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution . Before , i realized that since i can't boot any OS like Ubuntu , Fedora , Windows , etc. using their boot images , i should try to format my HDD completely . But i couldn't format my HDD using any of the boot image programs like Active KillDisk , DBAN , Gpart etc. Then i came across Ultimate Boot CD and booted from that . Then i chose BOOTMGR ( Multi-Boot Manager ) program on it and selected my HDD on it . Then i selected 'Zap Disk' which 'Erases MBR and tracks 0 & 1" . Now , i simply reinstalled Windows using my Windows installation USB . 
Note : This method deletes all the data on your HDD .

Comment: C'mon this is like very bad solution

Answer (score 1):

My Explaination is bad but this is the solution.

**Great Solution for this**

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XMFuN.png)

Generally Ubuntu when Dual Booted creates a recovery partition which is set to a system type partition. So if you want to remove the Grub menu you can delete this. But it has a problem.
If you try to delete it from the DiskManagement in Windows 10 it might cause some error.

Follow this steps to overcome this:

**Step 1**. Open DiskPart on your PC

1. Hit "Windows Key + R" to open the run dialogue box.
2. Enter diskpart and click "OK" to open a black command prompt window.

**Step 2**. Change EFI system partition ID and set it as a data partition

**Type the below command lines and hit Enter each time:**

> list disk (Find your Disk where it is installed)

> sel disk 1 (Do this if you have installed Linux in Disk 1 or External Drive)

> list partition

> sel partition1 (Select the partition which has the System type (Mine is Partition 2))

> SET ID=ebd0a0a2-b9e5-4433-87c0-68b6b72699c7

Shown Here:
[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bbtWa.png)

**Step 3**. Delete EFI partition with command line

**Type the below command lines and hit Enter each time:**

> list partition
> sel partition 1
> delete partition override

Boom You have done it

Answer (score 0):

You'll need a working windows 10 bootable USB drive/DVD. Use the official iso to generate these and they should boot. Once done, try `bootrec /rebuildBcd` from the recovery command prompt, along with `bootrec /fixMbr`

Comment: Like i said , i already have them and they work fine on my other laptop .But it just get stuck on the startup screen before i can even get to the "Repair Windows" button , on the affected laptop .

Comment: Really weird, something doesn't add up...formatting a partition cannot cause out of memory problems. What is the RAM in your system? What are the errors you encounter while trying to run other live distributions?

Comment: I encountered same errors when trying to run Mint and Fedora . I have 6GB RAM